# How can I make an embed with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have these lines of codes so far. However, I am not entirely sure how to make an embed that if the command executor reacts to an emoji it will proceed to the next embed message; and if it's someone else, it'll return.

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription("Thank you for using Norieko, please react below to see the command list")
message.channel.send(embed)

const modEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription("Moderation Commands: `kick`, `ban`, `purge`")
message.channel.send(modEmbed)

const miscEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription("Misc Commands: `meme`, `server`, `user`, `help`")
message.channel.send(miscEmbed)
```

Comment: This is what's called "pagination". Google search that and I have no doubt in my mind you'll get your answer.

Comment: Look about message collect reaction, and message edit function. You code will complete about 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Fields**
*It seems you wanted to react and sends the message, this could be better and less complicate!*

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, message) => {
  const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription('Thank you for using Norieko, please react below to see the command list')

  message.channel.send(embed1).then(function(message) {
   message.react('✅');
  });

  if (reaction.emoji === '✅') {
    const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Commands')
    .addField('Moderation', '`kick`, `ban`, `purge`')
    .addField('Misc', '`meme`, `server`, `user`, `help`')

    message.channel.send(embed2);
  };
});
```